# Sublime text not building python correctly

Tags: python, text

You can mark this as a duplicate as you need, but this is making me really tired of Sublime Text. I just got it today, and when I try to build python, this happens:

```
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\depia\floobits\ReverseString.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\depia\floobits]
[path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\TCS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Components\TCS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Users\depia\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps]
```

I can't build anything in python, and it is really annoying. Every time I try to build with Python, this happens. Any fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems python isn't on your path, you need to add it so sublime knows where the executable is

See this answer on how to do it on windows
[How to add to the PYTHONPATH in Windows, so it finds my modules/packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

It should be done by default on Mac, hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! This really helped!